# How to count string characters in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of characters in a string value without including the space as a count. For example, I want "Honda Civic" to return a length of 10 which is not counting the space between Honda and Civic.

```
_id:ObjectId("111111111111111111111112")
name: "Honda Civic" (String value)
```

Result: carNameLength:10

Comment: `.aggregate([{ "$addFields": { "carNameLength": { "$strLenCP": { "$reduce": { "input": { "$split": [ "$name", " "] }, "initialValue": "", "in": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] } } } }}}])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$split` and `$strLenCP` within framework to find the length of string(name) without the spaces.

You need to first split the name with space(" ") and then sum the length of all the strings.

Try this:

```
db.cars.aggregate([{
    $match : { //add your match criteria here, or you can skip this part}
},{
    $project : {
        name : 1,
        name_array : { $split : {$name : " "}} //split the name with space and store the result in name_array
    }
},{
    //unwind the array, so that we can store each string length 
    $unwind : "$name_array"
},{
    $project : {
        name : 1,
        nameLength : {$strLenCP : $name_array}
    }
},{
    $group :{
        _id : "$_id",
        name : {$first : "$name"},
        carNameLength : {$sum : "$nameLength"}//add all the string length
    }
}])
```

Read more in details at [$split documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and [$strLenCP documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/).